# UWP detect keyboard presses and release

Tags: uwp, keyrelease

I do not want to use a paint canvas or virtual keyboard, simply fire an event when key_A is pressed and another event when released.

I looked at [UIElement.keydown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx), but it seems to work with onscreen keys only

Answer (score 0):

Using `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;` should be working.

Comment: Hello did it work for you ? If so can you mark as anwer to close the thread ? Thanks :)